# How to embed .avi from localhost, and watch from iPad?

Tags: html, streaming, video-streaming, localhost, wamp

I've got a few movies that I have uploaded to my localhost/movies 
I was wondering how I could embed them into a html file so I could watch/stream then instead of download? I know how to connect to the localhost from my iPad/iPhone, but I can't figure out how to embed, thank you!

Comment: `<embed src="monsters.avi"/ width='100%' >` This works, but only on my pc "It's all I have in the index.html"

Comment: local host refers to only the computer it is on. find out what your computer's ip is relative to your ipad, it will be something like 192.168.1.103 , so then `<embed src=http://192.168.1.103/monsters.avi>` you can find out your ip by running `ipconfig` in a command prompt window and you want to take note of the ipv4 address

Comment: I changed it to '.flv' and used your suggestion, it works on my pc, with the ip, but when i enter it in my iPad, it just a blank page?

Comment: Gotta ask, is your ipad on the same network? And when you try to go to the address directly in your ipad's browser, does it find it? How are you hosting this, xampp or something? Are you running an ftp server?

Comment: Yes, same network, WAMP, it connects to all my localhost servers through the IP

Comment: Ah, ok, now I'm with you. Do other file types work? I don't believe ipad with play flv's natively in a browser.